# Refreshing an Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I created an `Activity` which allows navigating between pages with a couple of Buttons (Previous and Next). When the user clicks one of the buttons, the `Activity` (same) needs to be "refreshed". In order to do this, I set up the buttons to make a call to

```
onCreate(this);
```

after they set up the other stuff that the activity uses for the paging to work.

And it is working so far, but I'm wondering if there is a better way. Is there?

Comment: Specify what are these changes. Do they modify the UI? The logic behind? Some settings?

Comment: Calling onCreate() manually is a very very bad idea

Comment: @Maragues - Please see my other message bellow for explanation of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Famarri - What would be the correct way to do something like that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this trough refactoring:

Created a new function with the code that was being executed in onCreate (i.e. Layout initialization, database access and information display). The new function is called by the  onCreate method (when the Activity gets the "Create" notification) and at anytime that I need to "refresh" the contents of the Activity (i.e. when a button is pressed).

Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

You should rethink your approach. Having Previous and Next buttons looks like an iphone's `NavigationBar` View. Remember that in android you have the back button, so a previous button shouldn't be necessary.

If you wish to do it, check [Android's Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle). You should update your `Activity` on the `onStart()` method and avoid the call to `onCreate(this)` which doesn't sound good.

Comment: Doesn't it seam a little strange to only have a "Next" (and rely on the physical "Back" button) ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The activity displays data related to a certain day. The navigation allows choosing the day which is being displayed. As such, clicking one of the buttons changes the information which is displayed.

Example:

When the Activity first loads, it shows a given day - let's say August 23rd. Then when the user clicks the activity's "Previous" Button, the Activity shows August 22nd.

Then the user clicks the "Next" button and the Activity shows August 23rd again. If the user clicks the "Next" button again, the Activity will show August 24th.

---

Doesn't it seam a little strange to only have a "Next" (and rely on the physical "Back" button) ?

Thanks.